# Any way to build flutter desktop app for window(.exe) in macOS machine?

Tags: macos, flutter, desktop

I would like to build exe file from my macOS machine. How is possible?

Answer (score 4):

Per [the documentation](https://flutter.dev/desktop):

> To compile a desktop app, you must build the app on the targeted platform: build a Windows app on Windows, a macOS app on macOS, and a Linux app on Linux.

You can follow [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59735) to see if that changes in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.

But you can build your app using a windows emulator or doing a [windows dualboot with bootcamp](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468).

There is also online services who let you build flutter projects from a github repo but I don't think they can build a windows app.

Comment: There are a variety of online services that offer builds using Windows machines, including GitHub itself, that allow you to install the tools needed to build a Flutter project for Windows.